# Get FaceBook Friend Count

Tags: facebook

Is there a simple PHP or Javascript method of getting the total number of FaceBook friends? Twitter makes it super easy to do that, and I need to do the same for one of my WordPress installs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get your friends as a JSON object from Facebook, you can use their Graph API. Easiest way is to visit this page:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Scroll down until you find the Friends link in the "Connections" table. That link will give you a JSON object containing all your friends. Note that the URL on that page is unique to you and contains your access token. Don't share the link.

You can use this sort of code in WP to get and use that information:

```
$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get('YOUR_FB_URL', array('sslverify'=>false)));
$dec = json_decode($body);
echo count($dec->data);
```

You'll want to use transients or something similar to cache the data so that you don't ask FB for it all the time.

Comment: In your code above, is the YOUR_FB_URL the url to the JSON object?

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work? Any more feedback?

Comment: this works fine, YOUR_FB_URL is the link you get from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ under connections table >> Friends . make sure you are logged in to facebook and you have the developers app in your profile.

Comment: Yes, the YOUR_FB_URL would be replaced with the URL of the JSON object I pointed you to earlier. I tested this code, it does work.

Comment: Thanks Otto, I trust you and will test for sure in a bit.

Comment: Otto, I still can't get this to work. I've gotten the link to my friends array and plugged it in, but it won't work. I think it might have to do with the developer app not being fully added to my profile. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. That code does work. I tested it, it gives me the proper count. Maybe your server can't contact outside sites or something?

Comment: @Otto looks like this no more work. There is no Connection table. Do you know other solution?

Comment: Facebook no longer allows access to that data without access tokens. You will need to create an App through their system and use OAuth to gain access to that information. This code no longer works without the OAuth process.

Answer (score 2):

yes facebook does have a way for you to do that.
you can use the facebook [graph api and its user|friend connection](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)

something like this:

first create an application at
   http://www.facebook.com/developers/
   you might need to add the developer
   application to your profile and you
   will see a button "Set Up New App".

then download this facebook php
   wrapper from here
   https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/facebook.php

and then you can work with this PHP code:

```
<?php
//require the file you downloaded
require 'facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
                            'appId' =>'myid', //change to your APP ID
                            'secret'=>'mysecret',  //change to your SECRET code
                            'cookie'=>true,
                            ));

$session = $facebook->getSession();
$friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
$friends_count=0;
foreach($friends as $person){
 $friends_count = $friends_count + 1;
}

echo $friends_count;
?>
```

enjoy!

Comment: Hmm, that's not working. Do I need to change the /me/friends to anything?

Comment: yes, and the appId and secret in the array up there too

Answer (score 1):

You can get friend count by fql easily.

There is a friend_count field against the user table that you can query.

```
SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid = me();

https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid={any id}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of way to count the no of friends using Facebook Graph API with Php SDK, out of one i am telling..

```
$fbuser=$fb->api('/me/friends');
$access_token = $fb->getAccessToken();


$friend_count=0;
foreach($fbuser['data'] as $friends)
{
  $friends_count++;
}
```